# how to handle retrofit conversion for the formats of data?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have an API which generally returns response as

```
    {"boxes": [
        {
            "id": 40,
            "order_id": 100,
            "product_id": 18

        }
    ],
   "mBoxes": [
        {
            "id": 40,
            "order_id": 100,
            "product_id": 18

        }
    ]
   }
```

My app run successfully with retrofit2
but sometimes when the same api returns as with null value in the form  as in this sample

```
 {"boxes": [
        {
            "id": 40,
            "order_id": 100,
            "product_id": 18

        }
    ],

        "mBoxes":""
     }
```

In first case I trace it by making list in interface but the app crashed when the latter form of data is returned with an error of Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING . How to fix it. Any suggestions, solutions and ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: If Array is empty then send `null` . `"mBoxes":null`

Comment: the problem is api is not mine . I am seeking the solution in retrofit error handling. Have you any idea about it

Comment: receive response as String and map to object manually